# Мультиплатформенный 2d игровой движок с поддержкой c# и визуального редактора

Tags: c#, разработка-игр

Вот есть, например, Unity3d. У него прекрасный визуальный редактор, сам двиг очень неплохой. Так же там есть и поддержка 2д.

Но.... в то же время, Он жрет ресурсы лишние. Т.к. 2д в движке это псевдо 2д (на практике просто камера двигается в двух координатах вместо трех)

Знает ли кто двиг:

- с поддержкой c#
- визуальным эдитором (в стиле юнити)
- Мультиплатформенный(мобильные девайсы)

Comment: Не вижу проблемы с Unity2D - трёхмерных объектов нет, обсчитывать их не надо.

Comment: Юнити в принципе достаточно тяжеловесный. Вот представь что ты запустил, скажем, пустой уровень в юнити и на телефоне он висит открытый просто. И засеки время... А потом какую-то нейтивную пустую апликуху или же на 2д движке. Разница есть в том, сколько батареи сожрало за такое же время? :) А еще больше это будет чувствоватся на рабочем проэкте потому как часть графических операций будет делатся на чуть ли не на треть менее оптимально чем нужно... Вот потому и спрашиваю. :)

Comment: Какая-нибудь [такая](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/game_development/) наркомания, может? Там перечислены движки. Сам не вчитывался, но вдруг поможет

Comment: Про ксамарин знаю. Он, возможно, и быстрый(на девайсах)... Но нереально тяжеловесный в плане разработки под виндой. Я пару раз ставил... И, если чесно, далеко не самые приятные воспоминания о нем остались... Хотя, слышал что под маком все по-другому. Но у меня нету мака :)

Comment: Он невероятно тяжёлый в установке и при открытии проекта, а так - всё хорошо )

Comment: В таком случае, где можно почитать ТОЛКОВО про сам процес установки и подготовки "рабочего места" андроид-айос-разработчика под ксамарином? А так же запуск апликухи напрямую на андроид девайсе вместо эмулятора.

Comment: Почитать - не знаю, я [смотрел](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/xamarin-for-absolute-beginners-16182?l=VTH3ytnLC_2204300477). Запуск на андроид девайсе элементарно - так же, как в Андроид студии, насколько я понимаю. Драйвер от Гугл, драйвер от телефона - и при подключении можно запускать на девайсе прямо из студии

Comment: *(на практике просто камера двигается в двух координатах вместо трех)* -- это как раз ерунда, сейчас видеочипы так устроены, что это не имеет значения, особенно если выключить Z-буфер и рассчитывать на порядок рисования. Юнька тяжёлая больше по другим причинам :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Про Unity уже сказали, а так, просто на вскидку, то вот:

https://duality.adamslair.net/ - OpenGL, насчет мультиплатформенности не скажу...

https://waveengine.net/ - вроде как мультиплатформенность есть.

https://www.deltaengine.net/ - платный для мультиплатформенности, но есть свободная версия под винду.

http://www.monogame.net/ - на Mono.

http://atomicgameengine.com/features/ - судя по скринам, 2D платформеры в наличии.

http://flatredball.com/

Вот тут еще список движков на ГитХабе: https://github.com/showcases/game-engines?s=language
Правда, там оно не всё C# далеко, да и не всё 2D.

[Аналогичный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230834/multi-platform-2d-game-engine) на английском StackOverflow. И [еще один](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/109/what-c-libraries-can-be-used-to-support-game-development) на StackExchange.

Естественно, на полноту списка не претендую. Если погуглить, то результатов будет тьма, уверен. 
А вот что именно выбрать - это решать вам, т.е. надо как минимум хотя бы поверхностно изучить фичи движков и их особнности с целью понять, подойдут ли они именно для ваших целей.

UPDATE: 
Есть еще вот отечественная разработка: http://quad-engine.com/